# Classification data in SVM

Tags: matlab, classification, svm

i am beginner in Matlab programming. I want to define SVM classifier. I have some data that indicated pedestrian cross path by contiguous and connected X and Y points, When these X and Y points connected together show the pedestrian way. Eventually i want to define for example 50 X and Y (that indicate the way) in normal cross path class and some other way to abnormal cross path class. In fact some categories of X and Y choose for abnormal class and some categories choose to normal class (we have 2 classes normal and abnormal) . Could you please help me.

Comment: I don't think I got exactly what your problem is, but for svm training in MATLAB I would suggest you [VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/install-matlab.html), a great open source Computer Vision library with MATLAB wrappers. Here is the [tutorial](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/svm.html) for the SVM functions.

Comment: excuse me for make it hard, but i want to refer some point that consist of X and Y to abnormal class and normal class, but i don't know how could it possible!